# Ascending increasing random numbers

Tags: javascript

I need js function to increasing random numbers in  with delay like this:

```
var min = 5;
var max = 21;

OUTPUT:
6
--wait 1s--
8 
--wait 1s--
11 
--wait 1s--
15
--wait 1s--
21
```

Comment: Pick a random number generator and in formula use as minimum value the previous generated one...

Comment: "*I need [...]*" That's not really how SO works. We're typically willing to assist with your current attempts. But, you need to demonstrate your efforts.

Comment: What if the first random number is 21? Also, if it's 20, the following number won't be random. **Also, why in the world did you add a jQuery tag?**

Comment: Are there additional reqirements that you mention, for example that there should always be exactly five random numbers, or that `min` should never be included but always `max`?

Comment: Poorly formulated question, I want to increase this number in <div id="numbers"></div> <div id="numbers"></div> etc. Like this one http://jsfiddle.net/eqseX/

Comment: @user3067387: So, what specifically do you need that is different from that code?

Comment: I want to set min&max for each <p> so I guess it's need function

Comment: (Firt Post review) I would be more specific for questions. Asking for solving program homework in this way does most likely not result in a nswers and also is not something others can use as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var min = 5;
    var max = 21;

    function getRandomInt (min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    var interval=setInterval(run,1000);

    function run(){
        min=getRandomInt(min+1,max);
        console.log(min);
        if(min==max){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. Is it possible to show how these values change in <div id="numbers"></div> <div id="numbers2"><div> ?

Comment: The numbers doesn't increase every time, a test run gave for example `5,18,19,20,20,21`.